# Is the internal energy of a supernova blast wave always 72% of the initial energy released?

Tags: astrophysics, shock-waves, supernova

In *Astrophysics, an A-Z Introduction*, Page 67, Patrick Betts states that in the Sedov-Taylor solution for a blast wave, the temperature of a supernova shell decreases over time, but the internal energy always remains 72% of the original energy released in the explosion.

I can not find any direct reference of this 72% figure. Does anyone know where such a direct reference can be found in primary literature? Thank you.

REF: Betts, P., Astrophysics. Pediapress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find a *direct* reference to that specific figure, but the answer seems to be in the equations (31) and (32) of the [Taylor (1950)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/98395?origin=ads) seminal paper.

Taylor derived the following numerical solutions for the total kinetic energy and total "heat energy" (*i.e.* the internal energy for an ideal gas) evaluated across the entire blast wave:

\begin{equation}
K.E. = 2 \pi (0.185) \rho_0 A^2 = 1.164 \rho_0 A^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
H.E. = \frac{4 \pi}{(1.4)(0.4)} (0.187) \rho_0 A^2 = 4.196 \rho_0 A^2
\end{equation}

Where $A^2$ is a constant and $\rho_0$ is the density of the undisturbed medium. The numerical constants are all relative to the adopted adiabatic index (in the equations above, $\gamma = 1.4$).

As you can see, the ratio of Eq. (31) and (32) yields $(H.E.) / (K.E. + H.E.) \sim 78\%$. I assume that injecting a different value of $\gamma$ in the calculation of the constants would allow to obtain your figure.

In fact, [Chevalier (1976)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1976ApJ...207..872C) does state that the Sedov-Taylor solutions yields a kinetic energy that represents either 20% (assuming $\gamma=4/3$) or 30% (assuming $\gamma=5/3$) of the total energy. I suppose that R. Chevalier might have truncated from 72% to 70%, hence your figure would be true for $\gamma=5/3$.